# Convert PHP array json and send to Sql and fetch data back from Sql as Array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json, yii2

I have a project development using Yii2 framework, and in my project I've send an array into a single column in sql, this is the following **array** before send to Sql:

```
Array(
[0] => Array 
  (
   [0] => Array
       (
         [0] => first_name
         [1] => last_name
         [2] => age
         [3] => sex
       )
  )
[1] => Array
  (
   [0] => Array
       (
         [0] => Andrew
         [1] => Lugiano
         [2] => 18
         [3] => Male
       )
  )
[2] => Array
  (
   [0] => Array
       (
         [0] => Elizabeth
         [1] => Natari
         [2] => 21
         [3] => Female
       )
   )
 )
```

and this is the *code* in my **CustomHeaderController**:

```
$encoded_array = json_encode($arrayData);
$command_2 = "INSERT INTO data(array_data) VALUES('$encoded_array')";
$query_2 = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($command_2)->execute();
```

The column name in the Sql is `array_data` and has data type as mediumtext, and the table name is `data`.

and then I've try to get it back from sql through **SaveController**, and this is the code that I was used to get that data from Sql:

```
$sql = $connection->createCommand("SELECT array_data FROM data WHERE user_id=$userId");
$modelHeader = $sql->queryColumn();
```

but I got this as the result:

> Array 
>   ( 
>   [0] => [[["first_name",''last_name'',''age'', "sex"]],[["Andrew","Lugiano","18","Male"]],[["Elizabeth","Natari","21","Female"]]] 
>   )

That wasn't my expected result, this is what I need for my project(*just like before sended to Sql*)

> Array
>   (
>     [0] => Array 
>         (
>          [0] => Array
>              (
>                [0] => first_name
>                [1] => last_name
>                [2] => age
>                [3] => sex
>              )
>         )
>     [1] => Array
>         (
>          [0] => Array
>              (
>                [0] => Andrew
>                [1] => Lugiano
>                [2] => 18
>                [3] => Male
>              )
>         )
>     [2] => Array
>         (
>          [0] => Array
>              (
>                [0] => Elizabeth
>                [1] => Natari
>                [2] => 21
>                [3] => Female
>              )
>          )
>   )

How can I get the data from Sql just like my expected result?

Comment: You forgot to `json_decode` the query result…

Comment: It can't `json_decode`, because of the `$sql->queryColumn();` code set the result directly to an array. Maybe you know how can I get the result as a string so I can `json_decode` it? @deceze

Comment: May I know why I got downvote? thanks

Comment: `queryColumn` returns an array of columns. The first entry in that array is the JSON string you put into the database. So… `json_decode($modelHeader[0])`.

Comment: Have a google for sql injection

Comment: It's work, thanks @deceze

Answer (score 0):

Insert data as array only, whenever you want to return data use formatter. like this:

```
\Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
$sql = $connection->createCommand("SELECT array_data FROM data WHERE user_id=$userId");
$modelHeader = $sql->queryColumn();
```

For More Details [wiki](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/response-formats.md)

For existing code decode :

```
$sql = $connection->createCommand("SELECT array_data FROM data WHERE user_id=$userId");
$modelHeader = $sql->queryColumn();
$phparray = json_decode($modelHeader[0]);
```